# How can I use a generic interface in an IServiceCollection AddScoped call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a bunch of "builders" that I want to register with DI using `IServiceCollection`'s `AddScoped` call, but I'm struggling due to the generics on the interface. I've seen posts talking about using an "open" type but I don't see how to implement that as my resolved class is not generic itself.

All of my builders follow this convention:

```cs
public interface IOrganizationNames { ... }

public interface IBuilder<T> where T : IOrganizationNames { ... }
```

Then I have concrete types, such as this:

```cs
public sealed class SquareFeetRow : IOrganizationNames { ... }

public sealed class SquareFeetBuilder : IBuilder<SquareFeetRow> { ... }
```

I'm unable to figure out how to register that now. If I do the following it runs but nothing will actually get generated when injected:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBuilder<SquareFeetRow>, SquareFeetBuilder>();
```

In my class where I want to use it, I then try to do this:

```cs
public sealed class MyService {
    public MyService(IEnumerable<IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>> builders) {
```

The `builders` array is empty.  The goal here is to not itemize each builder type, but let the DI know all of them that are registered.

If I explicitly use `IBuilder<SquareFeetRow>` then it'll inject, but I'm wanting this class to just get all of the builders that implement `IOrganizationNames` as this class shouldn't really know about all the types.

Comment: _"but nothing will actually get generated when injected"_ - you have not provided code which attempts to resolve the dependency. Do you have a [mre]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine.  When you inject an `IBuilder<SquareFeetRow>` into a controller or minimal API, it will resolve to a scoped `SquareFeetBuilder`.

If you want a `IEnumerable<IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>>` then you must register one, eg

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEnumerable<IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>>>( sp =>
{
    var services = new List<IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>>();
    services.Add(sp.GetRequiredService<IBuilder<SquareFeetRow>>());
    //add others
    return services.AsReadOnly();
});
```

or register a custom service that has a method like

`IList<IBuilder<T>> GetBuilders<T>()`

Comment: David, please see updated question as I wasn't clear enough.  If I explicitly give the type then yes it will get added.  However, I'm wanting to get *all* builders that implement the interface, vs. having to list each type out in the constructor.  Hope that's clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is incomplete, because the correct answer would involve mentioning the use of (co) variance. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve a collection of `IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>` instances, you *must* register them as such, i.e.:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBuilder<IOrganizationNames>, SquareFeetBuilder>();
```

The above, however, will **not** compile unless you change `IBuilder<T>` to become covariant (meaning you have to use the `out` keyword):

```cs
public interface IBuilder<out T> where T : IOrganizationNames { }
```

Whether or not it is actually possible (or feasible) for you to make `IBuilder` covariant depends on whether its `T` is used as input (thus `in`) or output (thus `out`) arguments.